# Own library using Qt : undefined reference

Tags: qt4, embedded

As you possibly know now from my multiple topics, I'm embedding Qt 4.7.4 on an ARM system ; I just have one last problem. =/

I wrote a library that is using Qt and that I compile with qmake, in order to obtain a *.so* file ; that works. Then I wrote a soft that should use this library, and that I compile with a classical make. The problem is, when I try to compile this soft, I get a lot of "undefined reference" from my library ; all Qt elements are missing in fact. I saw that Qt libs are not found :

```
/usr/local/lib/star81xx-lsdk/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-uclibc/4.2.3/../../../../arm-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: warning: libQtGui.so.4, needed by /home/jdl/workspace-install/MY_ARM_SYSTEM/fs/usr/lib/myLib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/star81xx-lsdk/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-uclibc/4.2.3/../../../../arm-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: warning: libQtNetwork.so.4, needed by /home/jdl/workspace-install/MY_ARM_SYSTEM/fs/usr/lib/myLib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/star81xx-lsdk/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-uclibc/4.2.3/../../../../arm-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: warning: libQtCore.so.4, needed by /home/jdl/workspace-install/MY_ARM_SYSTEM/fs/usr/lib/myLib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Why did *myLib* compile good if it doesn't know where Qt libs are ? Can I add it manually to my soft Makefile ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling through cmd-line, you need to add `-L` to specify the path where libQtGui.so.4 and the others are, then add `-lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lQtCore` so that these libraries are linked to your application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot you have not added to your .pro file:

1. TARGET
2. CONFIG
3. QT
4. LIBS

Check.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just needed to add the path to the library, and to make a symbolic link to libQtGui with libQtGui.so.4 ;)